# Netbeans IDE 8.2 how to change c output folder

Tags: netbeans

Windows 7 (SP1) 32 bit, NetBeans IDE 8.2.

How do I change the output folder for C programs?

I searched for this long and hard before posting this.

I changed my root workspace folder to `c:\Users\Mark\Documents\Programming\Workspaces`

That seems to be working, and under that folder NetBeans created...

```
Netbeans/(project)/build/Debug/Mingw-Windows/_ext/c0b01605
```

I would like to get rid of the "build/Debug/Mingw-Windows/_ext/c0b01605" part (I can live with the "debug" part if needed.)

Then I changed the 'output' line in the project linker page [right click on project, select properties, build->Linker] to:

```
${CND_DISTDIR}/(project)
```

The output directory did not change.

What am I missing?

Thanks, Mark.